# parse odd dataframe index to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe that I've pulled from the EIA API, however, all of the index values are of the format `'YYYY mmddTHHZ dd'`. For example, 11am on today's date appears as `'2020 0317T11Z 17'`.

What I would like to be able to do is parse this index such that there is a separate `['Date']` and `['Time']`column  with the date in `YYYY-mm-dd` format and the hour as a singular number, i.e. `11`.

It is not a datetime object and I'm not sure how to parse an index and replace in this manner. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the excessive part:

```
s = pd.Series(['2020 0317T11Z 17'])
datetimes = pd.to_datetime(s.str[:-4], format='%Y %m%dT%H')

# after converting to datetime, you can extract
dates = datetimes.dt.normalize()
times = datetimes.dt.time
# or better
# times = dtatetimes - date
```